# How to redirect message/echo output to a buffer in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I'm writing a couple of helper functions for my use. They first call up `org-publish-project` and then call external scripts on that output. I'd like to collect all output from the execution in a temp buffer that pops up.

The external stuff is easier. The function `shell-command` accepts a second argument about a buffer where to send stdout. But `org-publish-project` only echoes stuff to minibuffer and it shows on `*Messages*` if anywhere. Could I somehow redirect all echoes to a given buffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no such redirect, sadly.  You can try to advise the `message` function, which will catch many of those messages, tho not necessarily all of them.

```
(defvar my-message-output-buffer nil)

(defadvice message (around my-redirect activate)
  (if my-message-output-buffer
      (with-current-buffer my-message-output-buffer
        (insert (apply #'format (ad-get-args 0))))
    ad-do-it))
```

Comment: Another similar approach would be using `cl-flet` with `message`, calling `org-publish-project` withing cl-flet form.

Comment: No, `cl-flet` would be of no use.  You could use `cl-letf` or the old `flet`, but I recommend the `defadvice` (or `advice-add`) route.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, as always clarifying (I miss the old flet, I am always confusing the alternatives :-) ).

Comment: I suppose this is as close as one can get. Or perhaps there'd be tools to check the call stack of those calls to `message`, see which stacks contain `org-publish-project` ::think :)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what `org-publish-project` internally uses to display messages, the following might work:

```
(with-output-to-temp-buffer "*foo*"
  (do-stuff))
(pop-to-buffer "*foo*")
```

Answer (score 0):

To temporarily redirect all message output to the current buffer, do the following:

```
(defvar orig-message (symbol-function 'message))

(defun message-to-buffer (format-string &rest args)
  (insert (apply 'format format-string args) "\n"))

(defmacro with-messages-to-buffer (&rest body)
  `(progn (fset 'message (symbol-function 'message-to-buffer))
          (unwind-protect
              (progn ,@body)
            (fset 'message orig-message))))

;; Usage
(with-messages-to-buffer
 (message "hello"))
```